# How to show woocommerce number of sales per sold product in a bar graph?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, graph

I'm using wordpress and elementor and woocommerce for my site : https://endoftheworldlottery.com

I would like to **show number of sold products** (which are in fact votes) **in a nice bar graph** on the [result page](https://endoftheworldlottery.com/results/).
I found a nice php code that outputs exactly what I want, but in text in a shortcode as seen [here](https://endoftheworldlottery.com/results/) :

```
function wc_products_allsold() {

    //  Get last week orders
    $all_orders = wc_get_orders(
    array(
        'limit'  => -1,
        'status' => array_map( 'wc_get_order_status_name', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
        'return' => 'ids',
    )
    );
    
    // Sum quantities purchased
    $count               = 0;
    $product_sale_list    = array();
    foreach ( $all_orders as $all_order ) {
        $order   = wc_get_order( $all_order );
        $items   = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_sale_list[ $item->get_name() ][]     = $item[ 'qty' ];
            $count                                   = $count + absint( $item[ 'qty' ] );
        }
    }
    foreach ( $product_sale_list as $product_sold => $value ) {
             echo "<p><b>$product_sold: </b> " . array_sum( $value ) . " vote(s)</p>";
    }
    if ( $count > 0 )
        echo "<p><b>All votes:</b> $count</p>";
}
print_r($product_sale_list);
```

I would like to output these data (sold product name and number of sales (or votes), if possible ordered by "popularity", to show them in a nice bar graph, ideally scaled.

I found some graph plugins (visualizer, wpdatatable, etc…) that accept either database (paid, but ok), or json, or serialised PHP array, or URL as data input…

I don't know which method would be better…

In the code I'm using, there are a couple of arrays, but I don't understand which contains what, and I don't know how to output them in a proper json file (using json_encode ?) or serialize them (but what and where ?)

Or maybe just code the graph in php ? But for me, a simple shortcode would be great.

Anyway, I'm lost. Can you help me ?
(I can pay for a custom code.) But I'm sure a simple solution is before my eyes…

PS : Do you like the idea of the site ? It's a fun personal project…

Comment: $total_sold_count = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'total_sales', true ); -- This may be helpful

Comment: thanks! but where? (sorry, I'm a noob in php)

Comment: I tried to add this at the end of the file :
`$fp = fopen('https://endoftheworldlottery.com/wp-admin/sale_results.json', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, json_encode($product_sale_list));
 fclose($fp);
but I get an error…